# How can I speed up this cuda program?

Tags: c++, cuda

I am working on learning CUDA.  I wrote this program to test if a number is prime.  It is many times slower than the cpu implementation.  Am I doing anything blatantly wrong and if so how can I speed it up (also I know I don't need to check evens I just haven't coded that optimization yet.)  I also gave the visual profiler a try.  It looks like it spends most of the time in the memcpyToSymbol.

```
#include <cuda.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdint>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctime>

__device__ bool _not_prime_flag;
__global__ void cuda_prime_kernel(uint32_t n, uint32_t sr)
{
    uint32_t d = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    if(d > 2 && d <= sr && n % d == 0)
        _not_prime_flag = true;
}
bool cuda_prime(uint32_t n)
{
    if(n == 2)
        return true;
    if(n % 2 == 0)
        return false;

    bool not_prime = false;
    cudaMemcpyToSymbol(_not_prime_flag, &not_prime, 1, 0, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    uint32_t sr = sqrt(n);

    unsigned int blocks = sr / 32 + 1;
    cuda_prime_kernel<<<blocks, 32>>>(n, sr);
    cudaMemcpyFromSymbol(&not_prime, _not_prime_flag, 1, 0, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    return !not_prime;
}

bool cpu_prime(uint32_t n)
{
    if(n == 2)
        return true;
    if(n % 2 == 0)
        return false;
    std::cout << "Here" << std::endl;
    uint32_t sr = sqrt(n);

    for(uint32_t i = 3; i <= sr; i += 2)
        if(n % i == 0)
            return false;
    return true;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << cuda_prime(1000001) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: C is not C++ is not C!

Comment: Use a better algorithm, that's a very naïve way to try the finding prime factors of a number

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep in mind that CUDA has to copy the necessary variables from CPU to GPU (`cudaMemcpyToSymbol`), and then from GPU back to CPU (`cudaMemcpyFromSymbol`). This actually takes quite a bit of time. If the number that you are testing is small, the CPU code will be significantly faster because it doesn't have to worry about that costly memory transfer. You will only see significant improvement with the CUDA code if you use really large numbers.

Comment: That makes sense. I just didn't think the overhead would be quite that large (1000x slower)

Comment: The overhead is a lot bigger than you think. Take a look at this: http://www.cs.virginia.edu/~mwb7w/cuda_support/kernel_overhead.html. It's pretty short and graphically shows the overhead.

Comment: For some reason I don’t see the cudaMemcpyFromSymbol in the profiler output.  It only says cudaMemcpyToSymbol under the runtime ABI section.

Comment: Hmm...that's a bit odd. It's been about an year since I've touched CUDA though, so I'm not entirely sure why that is occuring.

Comment: cudaMemcpyToSymbol could be replaced by a cudaMemset in this case. No need to copy a 0.